# Tree Hierarchy in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I just came across this question from 'HackerRank'.
The `BST` table contains two columns, `N` and `P`. `N` stands for Node, `P` stands for Parent:

```
 N  P
-- --
 1  2
 3  2
 6  8
 9  8
 2  5
 8  5
 5  null
```

Sample Output should be:

```
1 leaf
2 inner
3 leaf
5 root
6 leaf
8 inner
9 leaf
```

What I have tried is :

```
select     N, 
           case 
               when level = 3 then 'leaf'
               when level = 2 then 'inner'
               else 'root'
           end 
from       BST
start with P is NULL
connect by P = prior N
order by   N;
```

Although it gives the correct result, I  am not happy with the code as it hardcodes the name (whether it should be leaf, inner or root). Also this code will fail when there are multiple hierarchies in the tree.

Can someone please suggest any other elegant way of writing the same code so that it does not fail for multiple hierarchy?

Comment: Hi ! If anyone is aware of any good sql challenge site,Please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [`connect_by_isleaf` pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm), and the fact that the root will always have level 1:

```
select      n,
            case 
                when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 'leaf'
                when level = 1 then 'root'
                else 'inner'
            end 
from        bst
start with  p is null
connect by  p = prior n
order by    n;
```

Comment: Hi trincot ! Thanks for the answer . Can you please let me know some good sites where I can practice complex Oracle queries

Comment: You can create a free Oracle account and then practice on https://livesql.oracle.com/. Then there also is http://rextester.com, although it seems to run all scripts in the same schema, and so things often get broken. http://sqlfiddle.com also suffers problems (the Oracle database almost never works). But why not download and install an Oracle database locally.

Comment: Hi Trincot ! I have a local Oracle database installed in my system . Let me rephrase my question . Could you please let me know some good sites where I can practice sql challenges /questions?

Comment: I have no experience with SQL challenge sites. You are not satisfied with HackerRank?

Comment: Yes they do have good questions .But the number of questions is less .

Answer (score 3):

Oracle provides [a pseudocolumn  `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` to test](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm) for leafiness. The test for root is the same as the START WITH clause. Anything else is inner. So this should do you

```
select N , 
    case 
        when CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF =  1 then 'leaf'
        WHEN P is NULL then 'root' 
        else 'inner'
    end 
from BST
start with P is NULL
connect by P = prior  N
order  by N;
```

Comment: @MT0 - thanks. Shouldn't answer questions before my first coffee :)

Comment: Hi I am new to stackoverflow .I have gained the privilege of chatting . Can you please let me know how can I chat with someone ?

Comment: Hi APC ! Thanks for the answer . Can you please let me know some good sites where I can practice complex Oracle queries

Answer (score 0):

Please user Like below (For MS SQL Hierarchy)

;WITH Hierarchy(ChildId,  Generation,  ParentId) 
   AS
   (
       SELECT  Id, 0 AS Generation, ParentId
              FROM Table_Name AS FirtGeneration
              WHERE ParentId IS NULL
       UNION ALL
        SELECT NextGeneration.Id, Parent.Generation + 1, Parent.ChildId
              FROM Table_Name AS NextGeneration
              INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.ParentId = Parent.ChildId
   )

SELECT *FROM Hierarchy  ORDER BY Generation;

Comment: The question is tagged `[oracle]`. And the `[sql]` tag is used for general SQL questions, not MS SQL Server